# How to reduce cursor speed in Dosbox Turbo C?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, turbo-c, dosbox

I am running **Turbo C** using **DOSBox** in **Ubuntu**. But I'm facing cursor speed problem.
Actually the **speed of cursor** is so **fast**. It troubles me and make me irritating.

So suggest me the appropriate solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce/increase the mouse sensitivity in DOSBox Turbo-C follow these steps:

1. Goto the **dosbox.conf** file.
2. Then open it and set the **sensitivity** according to you.

   [image]
3. Then **save** the file.

Now open your DOSBox and enjoy it.

Comment: Changing this sensitivity still let my cursor blink like crazt